# Where is the loop-carried dependency here?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-optimization, vectorization, visual-c++-2012

Does anyone see anything obvious about the loop code below that I'm not seeing as to why this cannot be auto-vectorized by VS2012's C++ compiler?

All the compiler gives me is `info C5002: loop not vectorized due to reason '1200'` when I use the `/Qvec-report:2` command-line switch.

Reason 1200 is documented in MSDN as:

> Loop contains loop-carried data dependences that prevent
>   vectorization. Different iterations of the loop interfere with each
>   other such that vectorizing the loop would produce wrong answers, and
>   the auto-vectorizer cannot prove to itself that there are no such data
>   dependences.

I know (or I'm pretty sure that) there aren't any loop-carried data dependencies but I'm not sure what's preventing the compiler from realizing this.

These `source` and `dest` pointers do not ever overlap nor alias the same memory and I'm trying to provide the compiler with that hint via `__restrict`.

`pitch` is always a positive integer value, something like `4096`, depending on the screen resolution, since this is a 8bpp->32bpp rendering/conversion function, operating column-by-column.

```
byte  * __restrict source;
DWORD * __restrict dest;
int pitch;

for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    dest[(i*2*pitch)+0] = (source[(i*8)+0]);
    dest[(i*2*pitch)+1] = (source[(i*8)+1]);
    dest[(i*2*pitch)+2] = (source[(i*8)+2]);
    dest[(i*2*pitch)+3] = (source[(i*8)+3]);

    dest[((i*2+1)*pitch)+0] = (source[(i*8)+4]);
    dest[((i*2+1)*pitch)+1] = (source[(i*8)+5]);
    dest[((i*2+1)*pitch)+2] = (source[(i*8)+6]);
    dest[((i*2+1)*pitch)+3] = (source[(i*8)+7]);
}
```

The parens around each `source[]` are remnants of a function call which I have elided here because the loop still won't be auto-vectorized without the function call, in its most simplest form.

**EDIT:**

I've simplified the loop to its most trivial form that I can:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 200; ++i) {
    dest[(i*2*4096)+0] = (source[(i*8)+0]);
}
```

This still produces the same 1200 reason code.

**EDIT (2):**

This minimal test case with local allocations and identical pointer types still fails to auto-vectorize. I'm simply baffled at this point.

```
const byte * __restrict source;
byte * __restrict dest;
source = (const byte * __restrict ) new byte[1600];
dest = (byte * __restrict ) new byte[1600];
for (int i = 0; i < 200; ++i) {
    dest[(i*2*4096)+0] = (source[(i*8)+0]);
}
```

Comment: "`pitch` is always a positive integer value" - But does the compiler know that?

Comment: I just replaced it with a literal; same result. I also removed all but the first line of the loop to get a trivial case; same result as well.

Comment: I believe VC++ only handles `restrict` at the function-level granularity. So declaring the pointers as restrict inside the function does nothing. Try replacing them with allocations. Maybe it'll be smart enough to recognize that they cannot possibly alias if they come from different allocations.

Comment: The function's local pointer variables are assigned from global variables (legacy code base - don't blame me :P). Good thinking there; I'll see if I can get away with slapping `__restrict` on the globals and if that fails I'll try just with dummy allocations in the function.

Comment: Once I removed the expressions from the indexers `dest[i] = source[i];` it gave me reason 1300 which is "Loop body contains no—or very little—computation." I guess it doesn't like the complex indexers.

Comment: I'm actually getting 1101 for the trivial copy case...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's just say there's more than just a couple of things preventing this loop from vectorizing...

Consider this:

```
int main(){
    byte  *source = new byte[1000];
    DWORD *dest   = new DWORD[1000];

    for (int i = 0; i < 200; ++i) {
        dest[(i*2*4096)+0] = (source[(i*8)+0]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 200; ++i) {
        dest[i*2*4096] = source[i*8];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 200; ++i) {
        dest[i*8192] = source[i*8];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 200; ++i) {
        dest[i] = source[i];
    }
}
```

Compiler Output:

```
main.cpp(10) : info C5002: loop not vectorized due to reason '1200'
main.cpp(13) : info C5002: loop not vectorized due to reason '1200'
main.cpp(16) : info C5002: loop not vectorized due to reason '1203'
main.cpp(19) : info C5002: loop not vectorized due to reason '1101'
```

---

Let's break this down:

1. The first two loops are the same. So they give the original reason `1200` which is the loop-carried dependency.
2. The 3rd loop is the same as the 2nd loop. Yet the compiler gives a different reason `1203`:

   > > Loop body includes non-contiguous accesses into an array

   Okay... Why a different reason? I dunno. But this time, the reason is correct.
3. The 4th loop gives `1101`:

   > > Loop contains a non-vectorizable conversion operation (may be implicit)

   So VC++ doesn't isn't smart enough to issue the SSE4.1 `pmovzxbd` instruction.

   That's a pretty niche case, I wouldn't have expected any modern compiler to be able to do this. And if it could, you'd need to specify SSE4.1.

---

So the only thing that's out-of-the ordinary is why the initial loop reports a loop-carried dependency.
Well, that's a tough call... I would go so far to say that the compiler just isn't issuing the correct reason. (When it really should be non-contiguous access.)

Getting back to the point, I wouldn't expect MSVC or any compiler to be able to vectorize your original loop. Your original loop has accesses grouped in chunks of 4 - which makes it contiguous enough to vectorize. But it's a long-shot to expect the compiler to be able to recognize that.

So if it matters, I suggest manually vectorizing this loop. The intrinsic that you will need is [`_mm_cvtepu8_epi32()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531467%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

---

**Your original loop:**

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    dest[(i*2*pitch)+0] = (source[(i*8)+0]);
    dest[(i*2*pitch)+1] = (source[(i*8)+1]);
    dest[(i*2*pitch)+2] = (source[(i*8)+2]);
    dest[(i*2*pitch)+3] = (source[(i*8)+3]);

    dest[((i*2+1)*pitch)+0] = (source[(i*8)+4]);
    dest[((i*2+1)*pitch)+1] = (source[(i*8)+5]);
    dest[((i*2+1)*pitch)+2] = (source[(i*8)+6]);
    dest[((i*2+1)*pitch)+3] = (source[(i*8)+7]);
}
```

**vectorizes as follows:**

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    __m128i s0 = _mm_loadl_epi64((__m128i*)(source + i*8));
    __m128i s1 = _mm_unpackhi_epi64(s0,s0);

    *(__m128i*)(dest + (i*2 + 0)*pitch) = _mm_cvtepu8_epi32(s0);
    *(__m128i*)(dest + (i*2 + 1)*pitch) = _mm_cvtepu8_epi32(s1);
}
```

Disclaimer: This is untested and ignores alignment.

Comment: Accepted answer given the minimal amount of context that I've provided. The actual problem was to take 8bpp palettized color indexes and look up their ARGB DWORD colors in the palette, and then to alpha-blend them with some global ARGB color. I've done this with SSE2 intrinsics instead of trying to rely on the compiler to auto-vectorize.

Comment: I was trying to minimize the loop to the simplest case that would make the auto-vectorizer take over, and in doing so I destroyed the context of the original problem. I suppose my expectations were too great of the auto-vectorizer.

Answer (score 2):

From the MSDN documentation, a case in which an error 1203 would be reported

```
void code_1203(int *A)
{
    // Code 1203 is emitted when non-vectorizable memory references
    // are present in the loop body. Vectorization of some non-contiguous 
    // memory access is supported - for example, the gather/scatter pattern.

    for (int i=0; i<1000; ++i)
    {
        A[i] += A[0] + 1;       // constant memory access not vectorized
        A[i] += A[i*2+2] + 2;  // non-contiguous memory access not vectorized
    }
}
```

It really could be the computations at the indexes that mess with the auto-vectorizer. Funny the error code shown is not 1203, though.

[MSDN Parallelizer and Vectorizer Messages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj658585.aspx)